# Calculating piecewise quantile linear regression with segmented package R

Tags: r, regression, quantile, piecewise, quantreg

I am looking for a way to obtain the piecewise quantile linear regression with R. I have been able to compute the Quantile regression with the package  `quantreg`. However, I don't want just 1 unique slope but want to check for breakpoints in my dataset. I have seen that the `segmented` package can do so. While it works good if the fit is carried out with `lm` or `glm` (as shown below in an example), it doesn't manage to work for quantile.

On the `segmented` package info I have read that there is a `segmented.default`  which can be used for specific regression models, such as Quantiles. However, when I apply it for my quantile outcome it gives me the following errors:

> Error in diag(vv) : invalid 'nrow' value (too large or NA)
>   In addition: Warning message:
>   cannot compute the covariance matrix

If instead of using K=2 I use for example psi I get other type of errors:

> Error in rq.fit.br(x, y, tau = tau, ...) : Singular design matrix

I have created an example with the `mtcars` data so you can see the errors that I get.

```
library(quantreg)
library(segmented)

data(mtcars)

out.rq <- rq(mpg ~ wt, data= mtcars)
out.lm <- lm(mpg ~ wt, data= mtcars)

# Plotting the results
plot(mpg ~ wt, data = mtcars, pch = 1, main = "mpg ~ wt") 
abline(out.lm, col = "red", lty = 2)
abline(out.rq, col = "blue", lty = 2)
legend("topright", legend = c("linear", "quantile"), col = c("red", "blue"), lty = 2)

#Generating segmented LM
o <- segmented(out.lm, seg.Z= ~wt, npsi=2, control=seg.control(display=FALSE))  
plot(o, lwd=2, col=2:6, main="Segmented regression", res=FALSE) #lwd: line width #col: from 2 to 6 #RES: show datapoints

#Generating segmented Quantile
#using K=2
o.quantile <- segmented.default(out.rq, seg.Z= ~wt, control=seg.control(display=FALSE, K=2))  
# using psi
o.quantile <- segmented.default(out.rq, seg.Z= ~wt, psi=list(wt=c(2,4)), control=seg.control(display=FALSE))
```

Answer (score 0):

I came across this post after a long time because I have the same issue. Just in case others might be stuck with the problem in the future, I wanted to point out what the problem is.

I examined "[segmented.default](https://rdrr.io/cran/segmented/src/R/segmented.default.r)". There is a line in the source code as follows:

```
Cov <- try(vcov(objF), silent = TRUE)
```

`vcov` is used to calculate the covariance matrix but does not work for quantile regression object `objF`. To get the covariance matrix for quantile regression, you need:

```
summary(objF,se="boot",cov=TRUE)$cov
```

Here, I used bootstrap method to compute the covariance matrix by selecting `se="boot"` but you should choose the appropriate method for you. Check `?summary.rq` then "se" section for different methods.

Additionally, you need to assign the row/column names as follows:

```
dimnames(Cov)[[1]] <- dimnames(Cov)[[2]] <- unlist(attributes(objF$coef))
```

After modifying the function, it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the other answer isn't particularly clean, as you need to modify a package function.

Additionally, maybe boot isn't such a good idea for SEs, according to [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/421211/pooling-across-quantile-regression-analyses-from-multiple-imputed-datasets-quan).

To get it working a bit easier, add a function to your workspace:

```
vcov.rq <- function(object, ...) {
  result = summary(object, se = "nid", covariance = TRUE)$cov
  rownames(result) = colnames(result) =  names(coef(object))
  return(result)
}
```

Caveats from the Cross-Validated link apply.